# calling setTimeOut's function with object, unexpected result?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a JS puzzle, however I am not sure why using ralph.bark in the setTimeOut function does not work (does not log Ralph..)?

We are calling the bark function with respect to a specific object that is in scope (as opposed to this.bark which would make "this" point to window..), thus "this" should be set to ralph shouldn't it? Can someone explain why this does not work?

```
var Dog = function( name ) {
    this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
    console.log( this.name );
}

// make a new instance of a Dog
var ralph = new Dog('Ralph');

// make Ralph bark once immediately
ralph.bark();


// in 2 second we want Ralph to bark again
// this works

setTimeout(ralph.bark.bind(ralph), 2000);

// this does not work, WHY?
// setTimeout(ralph.bark, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout(ralph.bark, 2000)` doesn't *call* `ralph.bark`. It simply passes a reference of the function to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` then executes the function after the delay.  When it does, it will be something like `callback();`, hence `this` inside the function will refer to `window`.

How `this` works is extensively explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

Maybe this makes it clearer:

```
function bark() {
    console.log( this.name );
}

var Dog = function( name ) {
    this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype.bark = bark;
```

Now, whether you do `setTimeout(ralph.bark, 2000);` or `setTimeout(bark, 2000);` doesn't make a difference, since `ralph.bark` and `bark` refer to one and the same function.

Functions are first-class objects. They don't belong or are bound to anything, unless you explicitly do so (`.bind(ralph)`).

See also: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Then you haven't made the changes to the code that I did (did you notice that I defined a function `bark` at the top of the example?). Also, you don't have to try that, it's just a demonstration to clarify that accessing `ralph.bark` doesn't bind `bark` to `ralph`.

Comment: oh cool, missed that, thanks. How do we know that setTimeOut only stores the reference to the function that was passed in and thus does not take into account the object that was calling the function? Is this just 'common-sense'? I could not find this particular fact in the documentation, which was why I was not sure that was what was actually happening??

Comment: That's how "member access" works. When `setTimeout` is called and `ralph.bark` is passed, it is resolved to a value which is the function object. It literally means *"get the value of the property with name `bark` on the object that `ralph` refers to"*. And the function itself doesn't have an implicit relation to the object, just like my example should demonstrate. This is not specific to `setTimeout`, that's just how evaluating member expressions / function calling works.

Answer (score 2):

The way JavaScript binds `this`, you can't pass the function like that.

Same thing would happen with the following:

```
var bark = ralph.bark;
bark();
```

Fortunately, JavaScript has a way to bind functions to their `this` object. Try this:

```
setTimeout(ralph.bark.bind(ralph), 2000);
```

This is essentially a shortcut for something like the following:

```
setTimeout(function() { ralph.bark(); }, 2000);
```

See the MDN article on `bind` for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind